# SQL: output table of counts per field value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

We have the following data.

```
TestName  Stage1  Stage2  Stage3  Stage4
Test1     John    Calra   John    Calre
Test2     Calra   null    John    Calra
```

We need to implement a query which show data in below format.

```
User    Stage1count  Stages2Count  Stages3count  Stages4Count
John         1             0             2             0
Calra        1             1             0             2
```

Thanks
John

Comment: Used sub Query. But no successed.

Comment: Hi John.  You haven't specified a question.  Also, your post shows no attempt at solving the problem and looks like you want others to do your work for you.  Can you please edit your question to give us an idea on what you have tried and what isn't working for you?  There are tips on posting good questions in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `union` to normalize the data.  After that, a regular `pivot` strategy will work:

```
select  Name
,       sum(case when Stage = 1 then 1 end) as Stage1count
,       sum(case when Stage = 2 then 1 end) as Stage2count
,       sum(case when Stage = 3 then 1 end) as Stage3count
,       sum(case when Stage = 4 then 1 end) as Stage4count
from    (
        select  1 as Stage
        ,       Stage1 as Name
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  2 as Stage
        ,       Stage2 as Name
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  3 as Stage
        ,       Stage3 as Name
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  4 as Stage
        ,       Stage4 as Name
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 drop table tests
    CREATE TABLE tests(TestName varchar(10),Stage1 varchar(10),Stage2 varchar(10),Stage3 varchar(10),Stage4 varchar(10))
    INSERT INTO tests
    VALUES('Test1','John','Calra','John','Calra'),('Test2','Calra',null,'John','Calra')

select * from tests

    select 'John' as [User] 
          ,SUM(case when stage1='John' then 1 else 0 end) as stage1
          ,SUM(case when stage2='John' then 1 else 0 end) as stage2
          ,SUM(case when stage3='John' then 1 else 0 end) as stage3
          ,SUM(case when stage4='John' then 1 else 0 end) as stage4
    from tests 
    UNION 

    select 'Calra' as [User] 
          ,SUM(case when stage1='Calra' then 1 else 0 end) as stage1
          ,SUM(case when stage2='Calra' then 1 else 0 end) as stage2
          ,SUM(case when stage3='Calra' then 1 else 0 end) as stage3
          ,SUM(case when stage4='Calra' then 1 else 0 end) as stage4
    from tests
```